# Fixed decimals to 2

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have a view-bag returning double values from my controller to my view.
In a for loop I create a table like `<td class='tg-rtt4' id='ttl_@ViewBag.CostCenterList[i].CCCode'>@ttl</td>` to show my results.
The `@ttl` is a double variable.
Can I force it to always show 2 decimals?
Thanks in advance for your help!
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [String Format for Double](https://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/) you should be able to do this:

```
<td class='tg-rtt4' id='ttl_@ViewBag.CostCenterList[i].CCCode'>@String.Format("{0:0.00}", ttl)</td>
```